# Skipping Pundit authorization with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest, pundit

I have tests setup for Pundit no problem using:

https://github.com/ksimmons/policy-assertions

In my case I have my Pundit / Devise system supplemented with an enrollment type system to add roles etc.

When I test my controllers I want to skip the entire Devise / Pundit system entirely and focus on just the controller logic and not look at authorization which I will handle in my policy tests.

I am looking something like this (http://www.colorfultyping.com/disabling-devise-for-rails-integration-testing/#comment-4718) but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I think the key is the fact that 'authorize' is getting called in the controllers.  I tried even disabling Pundit by commenting out ':verify_authorized' in my application controller.  I want to have Pundit always authorize when I test except when I am testing the actual policies.

Comment: My workaround my be to just use the user fixture that has superuser permissions - this way Pundit always authorizes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to skip the Pundit authorization within controllers you need to stub
out the Policy class' `new` method to return a placeholder / mock object that
responds with `true` for the action policy in the action that is being tested;
e.g. for `FooController` my `FooPolicy` returns a new instance of itself that
returns `true` when its action policy `index?` is called within the `index`
controller action.

For Minitest it looks something like this

```
# - Minitest -
foo_policy = MiniTest::Mock.new
foo_policy.expect :index?, true

FooPolicy.stub :new, foo_policy do
  # your controller action test
end
```

You will create a mock object that will fulfil the role of Policy's new instance
object within the Controller action, and return that mock object if the Policy's
`new` method is called within the scope of its block during a test.

If you using Mocha, I believe the following will work also to achieve the same
as above, but without the need to specific the test assetion within its block.

```
# - Mocha -
foo_policy = mock("foo_policy")
foo_policy.expects(:index?).returns(true)

FooPolicy.any_instance.stubs(:new).returns(foo_policy)
```

Also, you can achieve a similar mock object with `mock = Object.new` and stub
method by defining a method for the `mock` inline like `def mock.index?`. This
also applies to existing classes, since Ruby allows you to redeclare a method
for a Class inline like so `def FooPolicy.new` and only persists within the
scope of the test. Knowing this we can have `def FooPolicy.new` and have return
our `mock` like in the following

```
# - Without a Test-framework -
foo_policy = Object.new # create a mock / double
def foo_policy.index?; true; end # stub a method

def FooPolicy.new # stub Policyclass to return double with stubbed method
  foo_policy = Object.new
  def foo_policy.index?; true; end
  foo_policy
end
```

*For completeness, I use RSpec and use the folllowing to stub out my Pundit
Polices within my controller actions*

```
# - Rspec -
foo_policy = instance_double("policy", index?: true)
allow(FooPolicy).to receive(:new).and_return(foo_policy)
```

As for Devise I use the following support test helpers and only include them for
Controller and Requests tests that require an User to `sign_in` before a test:

```
module DeviseRequestSpecHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  def sign_in(resource_or_scope, resource = nil)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    login_as(resource, scope: scope)
  end

  def sign_out(resource_or_scope)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    logout(scope)
  end
end
```

*See [Module: Warden::Test::Helpers — Documentation for hassox/warden (master)](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Test/Helpers)
for more information on `Warden::Test::Helpers` module*

This is because `Warden` is used within Devise that its Test Helpers are used.
This `Warden::Test::Helpers` module when included switches `Warden` into its
`test_mode!` and its `login_as` method will set your `user` object as the
`current_user` for the purposes of testing with Devise being used in your
application.

### References:

- [Test Doubles: in theory, in Minitest and in RSpec - Ilija Eftimov](http://ieftimov.com/test-doubles-theory-minitest-rspec)
- [Nobody told me Minitest was this fun « Plataformatec Blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/05/nobody-told-me-minitest-was-this-fun/)
- [RSpec & Devise: How to sign in users in request specs - makandropedia](https://makandracards.com/makandra/37161-rspec-devise-how-to-sign-in-users-in-request-specs)

Comment: Thanks @sonna for providing a complete answer using multiple test tools. Very helpful.